# Restricting only certain users to modify a row in a list display within the Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

My models.py looks like this :

```
class Change(models.Model):
   RFC = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Ticket_Number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Plan_Owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   Plan_validater = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My admin.py looks like this :

```
class ChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner','Plan_validater')
   list_display = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner','Plan_validater')

   fieldsets = [
    ('Ticket Details', {
        'fields': ['RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'Plan_Owner','Plan_validater']}),
   ]

   admin.site.register(Change, ChangeAdmin)
```

What I want to ensure that only the plan owner or the plan validater for a particular change can edit it.Everyone can view it,but doing changes to a row should be restricted to only the change or plan owner.Also they can only edit it and not delete it.Only the superuser can add or delete changes. [This link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/RowLevelPermissions) on the django site does mention some clues but my lack of experience with the framework prevents me from implementing it...

Comment: [This](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/) may help you

Comment: It sounds like you are going about this the wrong way. Why are you giving users access to the admin side of the site? Unless you are building a CMS of some sort, you can create your own custom permissions for the site-side for end-users. Don't let users use the admin side, let them do everything from the site itself.

Comment: did you try to use the clean function to check if the user has the adequat rights

Comment: Well..my app is simple enough to not write views for a public facing site..everything can be done within the admin panel of django itself and hence I was looking for more granular permissions in the admin..

Comment: @ArmanceWissal ..nope..how does one use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
class ChangeAdmin(ModelForm):


def clean(self):
    if self.request.user != self.Plan_Owner or self.request.user != self.Plan_validater or not :
        raise ValidationError(u'Permission denied')
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data
```

To access the current user, override the ModelAdmin.get_form, by adding the request as an attribute of the newly created form class .

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntryAdminForm

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(EntryAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.request = request
        return form
```

Comment: armance..thanks for this..I understood the first part of checking the permissions and raising a validation error within the form.However,I am not able to understand the second part.I don't have an Entryadmin form in my app.It gives me an error

Comment: this is exactly why you need the second part, you cant access request if you dont override the modeladmin